# Unexpected output in class inheritance code

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I tried this inheritance code and got an unexpected output. Kindly guide me where is my fault.

Child.py

```
from ParentClass import Parent


class ChildImp(Parent):
    var2 = 200

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self, 8, 3)


    def getData(self):
        self.var1 + self.Sub() + self.Add()


obj = ChildImp()
print(obj.getData())
```

ParentClass.py

```
class Parent:
    var1 = 100

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.firstNUm = a
        self.secondNUm = b


    def Add(self):
        return self.firstNUm + self.secondNUm

    def Sub(self):
       return self.firstNUm - self.secondNUm


obj1 = Parent(4, 6)
print(obj1.Add())
obj2 = Parent(9, 2)
print(obj2.Sub())
```

output:

```
10
7
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Where does this 10 and 7 come from?
Why there is a None in the output?

Comment: Becauase `ParentClass.py` doesn't have its code wrapped in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, that file's code will be executed when it is imported.

Comment: getData() returns None. You have print(obj.getData()) so it prints None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output is from the 3 print statements.

```
print(obj1.Add())    # prints 10
print(obj2.Sub())    # prints 7
print(obj.getData()) # prints None
```

Need a return on ChildImp getData() function otherwise returns None.

```python
from ParentClass import Parent

class ChildImp(Parent):
    var2 = 200

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self, 8, 3)

    def getData(self):
        return self.var1 + self.Sub() + self.Add() # <== added return

obj = ChildImp()
print(obj.getData())
```

Also good practice to add `if name == __main__` check in the parent class so only the main in the class called is executed.

```
# ParentClass.py
class Parent:
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj1 = Parent(4, 6)
    print(obj1.Add())
    obj2 = Parent(9, 2)
    print(obj2.Sub())
```

Comment: Keep in mind `self.var1` should actually be `Parent.var1`

Answer (score 1):

The output is from each of the following calls

```
10     # print(obj1.Add())
7      # print(obj2.Sub())
None   # print(obj.getData())
```

note that `Add` and `Sub` will `return` the computed value, btu `getData` has no `return` so will implicitly `return None` hence the last output.

Note that the reason those `Add` and `Sub` lines are executing is because of the `import` statement. If you only want those to run when that script is directly invoked you would modify that block to

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = Parent(4, 6)
    print(obj1.Add())
    obj2 = Parent(9, 2)
    print(obj2.Sub())
```

Comment: In addition if I were you I would explain why `print(obj1.Add())` and `print(obj2.Sub())` are being executed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

10 and 7 are the return values of the `Add` and `Sub` methods

The None is there because `getData` does not return anything

For all three values there is a `print` call.

Comment: As there is a call to `print` in each file that is not inside a function, it is executed when you import or run the python file